# Can't validate v-text-field [migrating from older version of Vuetify]

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've been migrating an old project from last year since Entity Framework 5 was released. Since I'm also migrating the frontend from the previous version of Vuetify I worked with last year (from 2.2.11 to 2.4.0), I've encountered some issues that I've had to look up online and fix, but I got this sudden issue that I can't quite lay a finger on and haven't been able to find a similar issue with an answer.

I'm trying to validate a v-text-field inside a v-card to not save a record if the v-text-field length is less than 3 or greater than 50 characters. Despite that I've followed up the same code I used last year to validate my v-text-field, I get the following errors on chrome console:

[image]
[image]

The last 2 errors from this image pop up when you click save when it should show the validation message:

[image]

The code used in the component is the following.

For the Validation message that should pop below the description v-text-field in red:

**VUE:**

```
<template v-slot:top>
    <v-toolbar flat>   
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">New</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
                <v-container>
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12">
                            <v-text-field v-model="name" label="Name"></v-text-field>
                        </v-col>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12">
                            <v-text-field v-model="description" label="Description"></v-text-field>
                                </v-col>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12" v-show="valida">
                            <div class="red--text" v-for="v in validaMessage" :key="v" v-text="v">
                            </div>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-container>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-toolbar>
</template>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {

        data(){
            return {
                categories:[],
                dialog: false,
                dialogDelete: false,
                headers: [
                    { text: 'Options', value: 'actions', sortable: false, class:"primary--text" },
                    { text: 'Name', value: 'name', class:"primary--text" },
                    { text: 'Description', value: 'description', sortable: false, class:"primary--text" },
                    { text: 'Status', value: 'status', sortable: false, class:"primary--text" },
                ],
                search: '',
                desserts: [],
                editedIndex: -1,
                editedItem: {
                    name: '',
                    calories: 0,
                    fat: 0,
                    carbs: 0,
                    protein: 0,
                },
                id: '',
                name: '',
                description: '',
                valida: 0,
                validaMessage:[]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            save () {
                if (this.valida()){
                    return;
                }
                if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
                    //Code to update
                } 
                else {
                    let me=this;
                    axios.post('api/Categories/Create',{
                        'name': me.name,
                        'description': me.description
                    }).then(function(response){
                        me.close();
                        me.list();
                        me.clean();
                    }).catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            },
            valida(){
                this.valida=0;
                this.validaMessage=[];
                if (this.name.length < 3 || this.name.length > 50){
                    this.validaMessage.push("The name must have between 3 and 50 characters.")
                }
                if (this.validaMessage.length){
                    this.valida=1;
                }
                return this.valida;
           }
       },  
   }
</script>
```

This is how it used to show like in my older version of the project:

[image]

I don't know if something that was changed in the Vuetify update version from 2.2.11 to 2.4.0 is interfering with the ability to implement this method inside the component to be able to show or hide the validation message. I'm trying to resolve this to avoid having to recur to 3rd party validation services like vee-validate or vuelidate. What could it be? Thank you for taking your time in reading this!

Comment: First thing that I noticed - you have a data property `valida` and a method `valida`. You have to change a name of one of them.

Comment: Okay I just noticed that mistake as well thanks for pointing it out! Though now despite not showing the method error, it only shows the first 4 errors (while not clicking on save).

Comment: Basically, the first error says you're calling for some method called `initialize`, but the method isn't defined in the component Category. The second says you're calling for an invalid (non-existent) method on a `v-btn` @click event. But I don't see a reference to non of it in the code you provided....

Comment: It was because I had an "initialize" method that I deleted previously referenced in a @click event as you mentioned. I removed it and replaced it with the current method I'm using for that button and it works now. You can post the same solution so I can mark it as the answer. Thank you for your help!

Comment: NP! Glad I could help! Posted it as an answer, along with a small suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up, these were the reasons for the errors:

1. There were a data property and a method with the same name - `valida`
2. `v-btn` component had a deleted method `initialize` provided to `@click` event.

And another tip as a bonus:

You have a `v-col` that spans to 12 columns: `<v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12">`. Since it should span 12 columns on every screen size, there's really no need to define the columns span for small and medium breakpoints. So in this case it really should be only `<v-col cols="12">` - will save you a little file size and loading time.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time in answering, it was very helpful! Will take into account your tip for the columns! :)